# SWIG/Python Memory Leak in pyfprint library

Tags: python, c, memory-leaks, swig

I am getting : swig/python detected a memory leak of type 'struct fp_img *', no destructor found.

I checked swig interface file but couldn't find anything that is causing this. Here is swig interface file : http://paste.ubuntu.com/10880764/

Any help will be appreciated. My code is :

```
import pyfprint

pyfprint.fp_init()
devs = pyfprint.discover_devices()
dev = devs[0]
dev.open()
fprint, img = dev.enroll_finger()
```

Comment: I think my answer at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13593596/168175 should explain it.

Comment: @Flexo I did checked your answer before. I am reading it again to see if i missed anything but I wasn't able to point out errors in swig file.