# SWIG: template return from python gives "memory leak no destructor found" warning

Tags: python, c++, swig

I have some python functions which I run from C++ side and I need them to return std::expected objects. What I did is this:

```
def do_operation(self):
    print("Operation done")
    return void_expected()
```

In Swig code I have something like:

```
%inline %{
    std::expected<void, OperationError> void_expected()
    {
        return std::expected<void, OperationError>{};
    }
%}

%typemap(out) std::expected<void, OperationError> {
    if (!$1.has_value()) {
        SWIG_exception(SWIG_RuntimeError, "Unexpected error!");
    }
    Py_RETURN_NONE;
}
```

But I am getting all these warnings running the python script:

```
swig/python detected a memory leak of type 'std::expected< void,OperationError > *', no destructor found.
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message you're seeing hints towards what's going on. Although my [older answer on that warning](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13593596/168175) does apply here it shouldn't and that hints as to what's gone wrong. Your expected behaviour is that for the case where a value is returned in C++ `None` is return in Python. Conversely if there isn't a value in the expected object then a Python exception is raised. In neither case are you expecting SWIG to create a Proxy object on the Python side for the `std::expected` result.

So the fact that you've seen this warning indicate that something's not as expected in your interface as written. And it turns out to be fairly simple - the typemap you showed comes *after* the place where it's expected to be used. So it doesn't get applied.

We can confirm this by constructing a small, complete example:

```
%module test

%include <exception.i>

%{
#include "expected.h" // TODO: include <expected>  insteadwhen I really have C++23 impl 
%}


%typemap(out) std::expected<void, OperationError> {
    if (!$1.has_value()) {
        SWIG_exception(SWIG_RuntimeError, "Unexpected error!");
    }
    Py_RETURN_NONE;
}

%inline %{
        class OperationError {};
        std::expected<void, OperationError> void_expected() {
                return std::expected<void, OperationError>{};
        }
%}
```

(I had to make my own expected.h since I don't have a C++23 compiler to hand!)

```
// Minimal parts needed to prove the point with this answer
namespace std {
        template <typename T, typename E>
        struct expected {
                bool has_value() const { return true; }
        };
}
```

And some Python to prove it:

```
import test

test.void_expected()
```

Which we can then build and run like this:

```
swig3.0 -c++ -python -py3 test.i
g++ -shared -Wall -Wextra test_wrap.cxx  -I/usr/include/python3.7 -m32 -o _test.so 
python3 run.py
```

This runs with no error. Swap the order of the typemap and the `%inline` with `void_expected()` declaration/definition around however as in your question and you'll see the exact same error since the typemap isn't getting applied.

---

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Indeed, if it's declared after it doesn't get applied. But now I realized that the typemap doesn't make sense, will return a python object in C++ side and crash. So I removed it because it was unnecessary, but I still have the warning. Any idea what to do in this case?

Comment: The use of a typemap seemed pretty sane to me - can you show a minimal example that shows it crashing? In terms of the warning you'll just need to show swig a definition for expected in the .i file, an empty definition will do. I'll edit to add an example later.