# Transform numpy.ndarray into "Eigen::Vector3d" data type through SWIG

Tags: python, c++, types, swig

I am trying to wrap a function whose argument is an "Eigen::Vector3d" data type, nevertheless, I would like to transform a NumPy ndarray into it. I suppose I would need to use a typemap in order to transform the data types. After trying it, I was not able to make it work. Could someone shed some light on it?
The files have the following content:

```
/*kinematics.i*/

%module kinematics
%{
    #define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT
    #include "kinematicsExample.h"
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cmath>
    #include <eigen3/Eigen/Dense>   
%}

%include <numpy.i>
%include <std_vector.i>

Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 4> forward_kinematics(const Eigen::Vector3d& q;
```

```
/*kinematics.cpp*/

#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <eigen3/Eigen/Dense>

#include "kinematicsExample.h"

Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 4> forward_kinematics(const Eigen::Vector3d& q)
{
    const double link1 = 0.5, link2 = 1.0, link3 = 1.0;

    //Pose vector of joints and hand
    Eigen::Vector3d p0, p1, p2, p3;

    Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 4> pose_matrix;
    
    //Calculate FK of the differents joints and hand

    p0 << 0.0, 0.0, 0.0;
    pose_matrix.col(0) = p0;
    
    p1 << link1 * std::cos(q(0)), link1 * std::sin(q(0)), q(0); p1 = p0 + p1;
    pose_matrix.col(1) = p1;

    p2 << link2 * std::cos(q(0) + q(1)), link2 * std::sin(q(0) + q(1)), q(1); p2 = p1 + p2;
    pose_matrix.col(2) = p2;

    p3 << link3 * std::cos(q(0) + q(1) + q(2)), link2 * std::sin(q(0) + q(1) + q(2)), q(2); p3 = p2 + p3;
    pose_matrix.col(3) = p3;

    return pose_matrix;
}
```

```
/*kinematics.h*/

#ifndef KINEMATICSEXAMPLE_H
#define KINEMATICSEXAMPLE_H
#include <eigen3/Eigen/Dense>

Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 4> forward_kinematics(const Eigen::Vector3d& q);

#endif
```

```
/*test.py*/
import kinematics
import numpy as np

q_input = np.array([30,45,60], dtype=np.float64);
q_input = np.radians(q_input)

print(type(q_input));
print(q_input);

pose_matrix = kinematics.forward_kinematics(q_input)

print("Pose Matrix:")
print(pose_matrix)
```

After executing this small code, I get the following:

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
[0.52359878 0.78539816 1.04719755]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/antmar27/Desktop/C++ /kinematics/test.py", line 10, in <module>
    pose_matrix = kinematics.forward_kinematics(q_input)
TypeError: in method 'forward_kinematics', argument 1 of type 'Eigen::Vector3d const &'
```

I tried the following typemap in the SWIG configuration file:

```
%typemap(in) Eigen::Vector3d const & (Eigen::Vector3d temp_vec) {
    if (PyArray_Check($input)) {
        PyArrayObject *arr = (PyArrayObject *)$input;
        if (PyArray_NDIM(arr) != 1 || PyArray_DIM(arr, 0) != 3) {
            PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError, "Expected a 1-dimensional NumPy array with 3 elements.");
            return NULL;
        }
        double *data = (double *)PyArray_DATA(arr);
        temp_vec[0] = data[0];
        temp_vec[1] = data[1];
        temp_vec[2] = data[2];
        $1 = &temp_vec;
    } else {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError, "Expected a NumPy array.");
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

But end up getting the following:

```
<Swig Object of type 'Eigen::Matrix< double,3,4 > *' at 0x7f380a9263a0>
swig/python detected a memory leak of type 'Eigen::Matrix< double,3,4 > *', no destructor found.
```

Comment: The warning you're seeing is because of this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13593596/168175 (i.e. it's that swig knows nothing about the type of the object returned by your function, the input typemap is working)